# JSPDF returning script error for creating PDF with ApexCharts chart

Tags: javascript, jspdf, apexcharts

I am trying to create a downloadable PDF of a chart I generate using ApexCharts. At the moment, I have just filled it with dummy data and am trying to get the download PDF option to work. However, when I try to run it, it returns a Script Error in the console. Here is my JS:

```
function display() {
  var options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'sales',
      data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91, 125]
    }],
    xaxis: {
      categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]
    }
  }

  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

  chart.render();
}

function demoFromHTML() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF();
  pdf.addImage(chart, 'PNG', 0, 0);
  pdf.save("download.pdf");
}
```

A link to the full jsfiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/eo8u073m/

I'm not sure why it isnt working as other, similar examples have worked with code like this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the error, the problem is your chart is not an image, you could utilize `addHTML` instead of `addImage` from `jspdf`.

Comment: Or utilizing retriving of image from `apexChart` using `dataUri` then passing it to `jspdf` as shown here

Comment: @noitse Used dataURI, it now displays the chart with the axis correct but the actual bars arent there. It should be viewable on the fiddle

Comment: It is due to calling it before rendering the actual data.
Try this https://jsfiddle.net/p9x52vtb/

Comment: Thats great, thanks for the help

Comment: I'll sum it up in the answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ApexChart` is being rendered as HTML in our dom, in your example you are trying to pass it through using `addImage` to `JSPDF` (You can see in your console raising this error for not passing image)

You can either pass `html` using `addHTML()` or export image from `apexChart` and pass that as shown bellow.

```
function demoFromHTML() {
  chart.dataURI().then(({ imgURI, blob }) => {
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addImage(imgURI, 'PNG', 0, 0);
    pdf.save("download.pdf");
  })
}
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/p9x52vtb/